# SF-Fantasy short story collection themed around the Yoruba smith god Ogun

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As per the title, I am looking for a short-story collection of SF, Fantasy, and whatever else might fall in between. I cannot recall what the book looked like, nor its length, nor if it was a recent book. I think I read this at the very least 11, if not 15, years ago.

This is a pretty long shot, as I highly suspect this book to only exist in my native language, French.

I remember strongly only two of those stories, which makes question if I am not mixing up two books.

I remember the common thread of the collection as being the more or less loose involvement/mention of the Yoruba/Voodoo smith god "Ogoun Ferraille" (~Ogun Scrap Iron).

One story is set in a near future where an incurable diseases strikes, that turns slowly people's flesh and organ to metal. It's extremely gloomy and has a mystic tone to it. Ogun is mentioned multiple time throughout as a sort of entity either responsible or at least strongly tied to the affliction.

Another story is set in a non-modern non-specific part of the world that I can only guess as being somewhere in a fantasied West Africa. Sword & sorcery vibe.

The main protagonist is a young man, living in a small village. A witch riding a giant beetle comes, demanding that one of the men of the village becomes her "eater of souls" (can't exactly remember the exact term). That is to say : her herald, body guard and lover. The vast majority of the men are extremely non-plussed by the offer, but she cannot be turned away. Witches are both respected and feared, but far more feared than respected. And that one is said to be the daughter of a quasi-mythical character.

The protagonist is chosen by the elders to be offered to the witch. His teeth are filled and his hair are removed one by one in a very painful ceremony. He then accompany the witch through her nomadic life, which seemingly consist of playing up the act of her reputation to get what she wants and letting our protagonist solve the fallout, in a generally violent manner. She has a goal in her travel that is somewhat mystical and unclear in nature.

The degree of magic actually involved in the setting is left very much ambiguous. The only clear fantasy element are oversized arthropods, such as the giant beetle that the witch and the protagonist use as mount, and a titanic centipede that a city uses as a living bulwark.

I also remember the story involving twin man-eater lions, one black and the other white, terrorising a village. But I might be mixing things up with something else entirely that was clearly based on the Tsavo man-eaters.

Aaand, that's about all I can remember :|.

My thanks in advance for anyone trying to take a shot at this.